# Changing a DIV's content

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dom, web

I would like to change my DIV.

```
<div id="main">
       <div id="one"> 
               <div class="red"> ... </div>
               <img class="avatar" src="img/avatar1.jpg"/>
               <span class="name"> John </span>
               <div class="text1">
                       <span class="age"> 16 </span>
                       <span class="sex"> male </span>
               </div>
       </div> 
       <div id="two"> 
               <div class="green"> ... </div>
       </div> 
       .
       .
       <div id="three"> 
               <div class="blue"> ... </div>
       </div> 
</div>
```

I need to change John's details. images and text.
I have learned that I can find John's DIV:

```
var item = $('#one');
var itemIndex = $('#main > div').index(item);
```

Now I can access that object:

```
$( "#feeds > div" ).get( itemIndex );
```

and get to it's children...

```
$( "#feeds > div" ).get( itemIndex ).children;
```

I don't know how to start changing the inner elements of the div

- **avatar's** img src
- the **name**
- the **age** and **sex** who lie inside text1 class.

I also feel my accessing the elements using an index is cumbersome, I thought I could simply find it by the main ID, and do the operations.

Any ideas?

Comment: As I suppose you want to get new info from your server though ajax, I would suggest using something like mustache.js to facilitate your work... If you don't plan to get new data with AJAX but already dispose of all data in JS somehow, then I think the best would be to write all of the HTML (= the same div for all your data items) and only show the item you want while hiding all others.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try `$('#one .name').text('whatever text you want');`

Answer (score 3):

```
var $div  = $( "#feeds > div" ).get( itemIndex );
$div.find('.avatar').prop('src','new src');
$div.find('.name').text('new name');
$div.find('.age').text('new age');
$div.find('.sex').text('new sex');
```

Answer (score 3):

```
var item = $('#one'); //Got John details container
var itemAvatar = item.find ('img'); //Got the Avatar
var itemName = item.find('.name'); //Got the Name div
var itemAge = item.find('.age'); //Got the age div
var itemSex = item.find('.sex'); //Got the age div
```

Not use `.text()` or `.html()` method to update those div. **For ex:** To change name use `itemName.text('New Name')`

To change the image.. use `itemAvatar.prop('src', 'next image url')`

Comment: Most efficient selectors out of all the solutions. +1

Comment: @Vega, could you please explain why use `find` rather than @danwoods solution?

Comment: @Ted Nothing in specific.. it Danwoods `$('#one .name')` will be internally using `.find` also I reduce the call to `$('#one')` as it is saved in `item`.

Answer (score 0):

```
var johnsDiv = $('#one'); 
johnsDiv.find('img').attr("src", "http://newurl.com"); 
johnsDiv.find('.name').text("New Name"); 
johnsDiv.find('.age').text("17");
```

Answer (score 0):

For changing all:

```
var newTxt = "yourNewTxt";
var newSrc = "yourNewSource";

$("#main > div").each(function() {
    $(".name",this).text(newTxt);
    $(".avatar",this).attr("src",newSrc);
});
```

Just changing John (div#one):

```
$("#one .name").text("yournewtext");
$("#one .avatar").attr("src", "yournewsource");
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$( "#main > div" ).each(function(){
     $div.find('.avatar').prop('src','new src');
     $div.find('.name').text('new name');
     $div.find('.age').text('new age');
     $div.find('.sex').text('new sex');
});
```